# PrivateObject class not found in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on a project developed in .Net Core 2.0. I need to write some unit tests for some classes having private methods and for this purpose i would need PrivateObject utility class. I don't know why but i am unable to find/access this class? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it exists in .net core 2.0. See also [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/366) issue

Comment: Then whats the way to test private methods? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Search here on SO, there are many examples floating around involving reflection. Some (maybe even most?) would argue that you shouldn't test private methods in the first place. But that's a whole different discussion which I won't get into.

Comment: I'll get into it - private methods are not part of your class's public surface area, so any way of testing them should go through your class's public methods.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Microsoft has decided that they do not want to include this pattern into .Net Core:

https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/366#issuecomment-580147403

> We discussed this internally and decided that we don't want to introduce this pattern back into the framework.